# JS argument bind not working

Tags: javascript

```
function pubsub(){

  var events = {};

 var self = this;
     self.on   = registerEvent;
     self.emit = triggerEvent;

function registerEvent(eventName,eventCb){

    if(events[eventName] === undefined){
        events[eventName] = {
            'counter'    : 0,
            'subscribers': {},
            'length'     : 0
        }   
    }

    var counter = events[eventName].counter++;

    events[eventName].subscribers[counter] = eventCb;
    events[eventName].length = Object.keys(events[eventName].subscribers).length;

    var unsubscribeObj = unsubscribe.bind(eventName,counter);

    return {'unsubscribe':unsubscribeObj};

} 

function triggerEvent(eventName,param){

    if(events[eventName] !== undefined && events[eventName].length){
        var eventList = Object.keys(events[eventName].subscribers);
        for(var index in eventList){
            var eventKey = eventList[index];
            events[eventName].subscribers[eventKey].apply({},param);
        }           
    }

 } 

  function unsubscribe(eventName,counter){

     if(events[eventName].subscribers[counter] !== undefined){
        delete events[eventName].subscribers[counter];
         events[eventName].length =    Object.keys(events[eventName].subscribers).length;
     }else{
        console.warn("Event not subscribed");
     }
  }
 }
```

I am trying to write a pubsub program. everything works fine except the 
unsubscribe function.

```
    var unsubscribeObj = unsubscribe.bind(eventName,counter);
    return {'unsubscribe':unsubscribeObj};
```

to the unsubscribe i am passing arguments threw bind, but its not working when do call from outside.

```
var pObj = new pubsub(); // Works Fine
var e1 =  pObj.on('event1',function(data){ alert(data); }); 
pObj.emit('event1',["hi"]);
e1.unsubscribe()
```

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribers' of undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first argument to `bind` is the value to use as `this` when calling the original function; the arguments to call it with are then *after* that. So the line

```
var unsubscribeObj = unsubscribe.bind(eventName,counter);
```

creates a function that will get called with `this` referring to `eventName` and `counter` as its **first** argument. But your `unsubscribe` expects `eventName` as the first argument and `counter` as the *second* argument.

If you want both `eventName` and `counter` arguments to be *arguments*, pass a different first argument to `bind`. If you don't care what `this` is in `unsubscribe`, `null` is usually what you pick:

```
var unsubscribeObj = unsubscribe.bind(null, eventName, counter);
```

More about `bind`: [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-function.prototype.bind) | [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the parent property exists before the comparison.

```
function unsubscribe(eventName,counter){

  if(events[eventName] && events[eventName].subscribers[counter] !== undefined){
//---^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
     delete events[eventName].subscribers[counter];
     events[eventName].length =    Object.keys(events[eventName].subscribers).length;
  }else{
     console.warn("Event not subscribed");
  }
}
```

It's because this error:

> `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribers' of undefined`

Is produced because `events[eventName]` is undefined, so `events[eventName].suscribers` doesn't exist.

You avoid the error with this change.

Comment: That's not why it's undefined.

Comment: I am reading your answers. Maybe I am mistaken, but I think that's an improvement however :)  thanks for your comment

Comment: No when i add breakpoint over there the eventName and counter has some invalid data..

Comment: @balaphp what does it means?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to bind context you should do something like this:

```
var unsubscribeObj = unsubscribe.bind(this);
return {'unsubscribe':unsubscribeObj(eventName,counter)};
```